# Balanced Quad Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

how can I build a balanced quad tree.
Thanks, Marcos

Comment: This is not for homework.I search on the internet, but I couldn't understand the process.

Comment: @Rob the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Balancing is traditionaly a part of "k-D Tree" algorithm, which is superset for octrees. Try e.g. [wikipedia page on this algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)